# First Substrate Chain

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

When i run this command according to the documentation.

```
**cargo build**
```

I recived this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfESo.png)

I didn`t find any solution for this.

This is the tutorial link.
https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing `protobuf` installation.

You can refer to official [Substrate documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/) for further information on what you need to setup to run a node. I suggest you check the [Install](https://docs.substrate.io/install/) section